# Calling pointer to Array in C library from swift closure

Tags: swift, callback, nsarray, closures

I find information that comes close, but doesn't quick go far enough in answering this question and am just hitting my head against the wall.

I have a C-based library that calling in Objective-C goes like this:

```
[access execute:@"string" completion:^(NSArray* results) {
            [self process:results];
            [access disconnect];
        }];
```

I'm after the contents of *results*, which is a variable multi-dimensional (array of arrays) chunk of data that can't be predicted ahead of time.

I have tried several things, including

```
access.execute("string") { (sqlArray:NSArray) -> Void in
            NSLog("something")
       }
```

but get a set of errors:

- Anonymous closure arguments cannot be used inside a closure that has explicit arguments
- Cannot convert value of type '(NSArray) -> Void' to expected argument type '(([AnyObject]!) -> Void)!'

I think I need an inout in there as well since I need the contents of the NSArray*. What am I missing? The bridging-header is set up and another call that only passes a Bool works great.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the parameter as an Any?

Comment: First, change `NSArray` to `[AnyObject]!` to take of the second error.

Comment: Okay that helped!
client.execute("test", completion: { (sqlArray: [AnyObject]!) -> Void in
                    NSLog("hi")
                })
works, but then can I treat sqlArray as an array?

Comment: Are you still seeing the first error after that?

Comment: `sqlArray` is an array of `AnyObject`.  You'll need some casting to get at the contents.  What kinds of things can be in `sqlArray`?

Comment: I think the first error was actually caused because this was already within a closure.

Comment: Thanks!

It's actually the results of a sql query, so rows of NSDictionary.